# в чем ошибка ?нужно ,если встречается 0 ,все,что под ним сделать так же нулем и вывести сумму массива

Tags: javascript

При запуске данной функции пишет : Cannot set property '0' of undefined

```
пример массива : matrix =
         [[0, 1, 1, 2], 
          [0, 5, 0, 0], 
          [2, 0, 3, 3]] ;




function matrixElementsSum(matrix) {
        let sum = 0;
        for (let i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) {
          for (let j = 0; j < matrix[i].length; j++) {
            if (matrix[i][j] != 0) {
              sum += matrix[i][j];
            } else {
              matrix[i + 1][j] = 0;
            }
          }
        }
        console.log(sum);
        return sum;
}
```

Comment: Может быть, сначала Вы нам скажете в чем ошибка?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В строке

```
matrix[i + 1][j] = 0;
```

Вы залезаете за последнюю строку массива.

```
if (matrix[i][j] != 0 || i == matrix.length - 1) {
```

```js
let matrix = [
  [0, 1, 1, 2], 
  [0, 5, 0, 0], 
  [2, 0, 3, 3]
];

function matrixElementsSum(matrix) {
  let sum = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < matrix[i].length; j++) {
      if (matrix[i][j] != 0 || i == matrix.length - 1) {
        sum += matrix[i][j];
      } else {
        matrix[i + 1][j] = 0;
      }
    }
  }
  return sum;
}

console.log(matrixElementsSum(matrix));
```

Answer (score 0):

Ошибка: `matrix[i + 1][j]` - i+1 затрагивает следующую после последней строку, то есть  несуществующую. Перепишите этот момент или просто добавьте проверку, например:

```js
let matrix = [  [1, 0, 3],  [4, 5, 6],  [7, 8, 9]]; //example matrix
let sum = 0;
for (let i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) {
  for (let j = 0; j < matrix[i].length; j++) {
    if (matrix[i][j] != 0) {
      sum += matrix[i][j];
    } else {      
      if (i + 1 <  matrix.length) 
        matrix[i + 1][j] = 0;
    }
  }
}
console.log(sum);
```